# Creating a Text Classifier with Other data features in Tensorflow 2.0/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

**Main question:** How do I create a neural network that can classify text data along with numerical features?

It sounds simple, but I must not be understanding something correctly.

## Background

I'm trying to build a text classifier (for the first time) using TensorFlow 2/Keras to look through app store reviews and classify them into the following categories: `happy, pricingIssue, techIssue, productIssue, miscIssue`

I have a data set that contains: `star_rating, review_text` and the associated labels.

## Problem

My understanding from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub) from TensorFlow is that I need to use the tensorflow hub layer to embed the sentences as as a fixed shape output.

```
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"

hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
```

And then I would build the model using that as my input layer.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

So my question is, where do I insert the numerical rating into the data into the model?

## Potential Solutions?

**Use two input layers and merge them somehow?** I would think that I would want to use the hub layer to embed the data, another input layer for numerical data, and then pipe them both into the next layer?

**Do I embed the string first and then append the rating to that?** I could also see creating a function that preprocesses the data into the array, and appends the rating onto the end of the embedded string, and just use the whole thing as the input object.

I'm stumped and any guidance is helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with an expert, both of the above solutions can work, but have different trade offs:

- Using two input layers: You can do this, but not using a sequential model, since this is no longer in sequence. It's a more traditional graph
- Append the string first: Because the embedded layer is pre-trained, it doesn't need to happen inside the model, and the text can be embedded and then added into a tensor along with the numerical rating.

Since I'm the most familiar with Tensorflow 2 and Keras, I opted for the 2nd choice, so I can continue to use a sequential model.

Answer (score 1):

There’s another option for adding in non-text data to text models: make the data textual. The exact way you do this depends on the tokenizer you are using, and how your model handles words it hasn’t seen before (OOV words). But, similar to how you might see special tokens like `__EOS__` to tell the model that one sentence ended and the next is beginning, you could prepend a text version of the rating to the review string: `review_string = “_5_stars_ “ + review_string`.

This sounds like such a hack it can’t possibly work, but I’ve talked to someone at AWS using it in production to pass metadata to a text model.